# Error: java: package R does not exist

Tags: android, intellij-idea, push-notification

Im new to android development coding my first app. I know this question has been asked many time but im still unable to solve the problem. I guess if i explain my scenario someone might able to help me solve the problem.

I've followed a tutorial and successfully implemented GCM Push Notification. Now i want to add this functionality to my existing android app. So i copied all the files to my app and when i build project i get:

```
Error:(39, 25) java: package R does not exist
```

All XML files are good, no errors.

Package name of my Push Notification app is:

```
com.androidhive.pushnotifications
```

Folder structure of my app is:

```
- src
 -- com
  --- funstuff
   ---- pushnotifications (.java files here)
```

Every thing works fine in my test app that i created following tutorial, but when i copied files into my project im getting package R does not exist error.

Am i doing something wrong? Is there another way of importing functionality into app without disturbing it?

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Im using intelliJ IDE.

Comment: what is the package name in manifest file?

Comment: package="com.funstuff"

Comment: now see in the java file what is the package name?

Comment: in existing app's files is com.funstuff and the files i copied from push notification app had com.androidhive.pushnotifications so i changed them to com.funstuff.pushnotifications

Comment: pushnotifications is your class name?

Comment: pushnotification is the folder that i created as a subfolder under my src folder.

Comment: then your package should be "com.funstuff.pushnotification"..

Comment: my existing app is com.funstuff so package name in manifesst is com.funstuff. I created a new folder pushnotifications under src folder and copied all files from tutorial there and imported com.funstuff.pushnotifications (intelliJ auto imported this). Do is still need to change package name to com.funstuff.pushnotification?