# Intellij IDEA 14 - Package R does not exist

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Well, I recognize that this has been asked before, but in browsing the other answers:
[IntelliJ IDEA - Can't build anything, always get "package R does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686289/intellij-idea-cant-build-anything-always-get-package-r-does-not-exist)
[Error: java: package R does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052254/error-java-package-r-does-not-exist)
etc.
none of the solutions work.

This is for a project that was building fine until at least the last couple days, so whatever is causing the problem must be new.

**Symptoms:**
Attempting to to a Build > Rebuild Project fails.  I see the step for compiling generates sources go by in the status bar, but the next compilation step fails with the dreaded "java: package R does not exist."

R is found just fine in the IDE, so only compilation fails, suggesting there is a problem with the compilation of the generated sources.  This seems borne out by the fact that in the out/production/[module] directory, only some resource files show up, no compiled classes, nothing in the "generated" sbupackage, a no apk file.

Interestingly, when I connect my phone to the computer and try running the application on the device, new changes are picked up, so something is being successfully built somewhere.

**Things I've tried:**
Per the other threads I've tried:

1. Doing a full rebuild.
2. Restarting IntelliJ (including with invalidating caches)
3. Restarting the computer.
4. Checking that the gen package is included under sources.
5. Checking for any Excludes (there are none)
6. Deleting the stub R file and forcing IntelliJ to regenerate it (which it does promptly)
7. Confirming that there is an Android facet on the module.
8. Double-checking that the manifest xml file has not changed and that the referenced activity is correct.
9. Checked that exclude output path is not checked (it's greyed as I'm inheriting from the project compile path, but I tried switching and manually unchecking it... no luck).

The only recent changes in xml were:

- A new item in a menu file.  I tried removing it to see if somehow that was an issue even though there were no errors reported, but the problem persisted.
- I moved a View class to a subpackage of its prior package.  That View class is referenced once in a layout xml and I confirmed that the xml was updated with the new package name.

So at this point I'm out of ideas. Sorry to rehash a somewhat common question.

Comment: Hm, I've observed that after last updated. Not able to build any project (even if after Ctrl+F10 it builds - during run, there's no resources class found and crash observed). Haven't faced that issue in last year using Idea. Believe smb brake something in hope that everybody uses gradle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same problem and it definitely related to last update of the IDE. My version is IU-139.1117.1
Before the update Build -> 'Rebuild Project' was working ok in a windows and a mac installation of the IDE. I updated windows first and 'Rebuild Project' shows the error 'Package R does not exist' even for a new Android project. Same error apeared in mac installation imediately after the update. 'Make project', 'Make module' and 'Compile' commands on the Build menu are all working ok with no error only 'Rebuild project' raises the error.
For a new Gradle Android project everything works ok. It seems something is wrong with last update.

Comment: Thaks to sandrstar's comment, I went digging around the JetBrains developer forum and found this:  
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135831  
which references this thread.  
https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5533840#5533840  
I got my hands on the 14.0.2 installer, so if the remove-and-readd-module technique mentioned in the thread doesn't work I'll revert.

Comment: Had the same issue. Since I don't know how to revert to 14.0.2, I installed Android Studio. That worked.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to revert either, so I just downloaded the 14.0.2 installer and did a complete uninstall-reinstall.
There was no convenient link to the 14.0.2 version under "prior versions" but editing the url manually to http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-14.0.2.exe did the trick.  When uninstalling, there's an option to keep settings info so I didn't have to do any re-customization.

(note: If you need a different OS or community edition, find a corresponding link here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Previous+IntelliJ+IDEA+Releases and change the version #).

Answer (score 10):

It is reported issue in IDEA 14.0.3 (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135234).

You can try to `Compile Module (Ctrl-Shift-F9)` for the module that contains missing R file. It works for me (but I have to do this every time i add/remove items in resources).

Comment: Looks like there are two issues for it.  I tried just compiling the one module, it didn't seem to stick.  Thanks for linking to the 2nd issue.

Comment: appears to be fixed in 14.1. Thanks for the link to the bug report.

Comment: @MichaelLevy Confirmed.  As of 3/27, Just update your intellij IDE to 14.1.

Comment: You can also compile a specific file within a module if it is being the problem child.

Answer (score 4):

don't use Rebuild Project, use Make Project and refresh your project,maybe you should try it a few more times.

Comment: Did that too.  Per previous comments/answers this turned out to be an issue with the 14.0.3 release.

Answer (score 0):

Try File | Invalidate Caches. This is solve my problem.

Comment: Did that (#2 under "things I've tried").  Reverting to 14.0.2 worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot wait for a officially stable build, install IDEA EAP 14.0.4 (IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.4 EAP build 139.1408, released on February 20th, 2015) from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP

I've just solved all issues and rebuild project works again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the 14.1 update of  intelliJ IDEA, available now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Windows 7 box today with a Java 7 Gradle project, using IntelliJ 14.1.5.

The problem was that somehow the classpath was "too long", but IntelliJ gave me only those strange "java: package foo does not exist" compile error's.

The usual tricks (see also above) did not help.

The workaround was to shorten the classpath a bit, in my case setting GRADLE_USER_HOME to c:/.gradle (was before c:/users/myusername/.gradle). After resyncing the gradle project everything worked fine.

The problem was therefor obviously IMO some kind of windows filesystem path length restriction.